# Python 3 dictionary find all elements and their key path

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, diff

Given a dictionary like below, what I'd like to do is find all elements (keys+data) and their full root key path. If the data is a string it returns the data and the full key root. If the data is a dict, then it returns the first key inside that dict as the data and the full key root.

```
a = {
  "level1_key": {
    "level2_key": {
      "level3_key": {
        "status": "down"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example, the first key has no root, and it's data is a dict, so return the current key as data and no parent keys.

```
Key = None
Data = level1_key
```

The data for level2_key is a dict, so return the current key and it's parents.

```
Key = level1_key
Data = level2_key
```

```
Key = level1_key.level2_key
Data = level3_key
```

```
Key = level1_key.level2_key.level3_key
Data = status
```

The last keys data is a string, so return the string as data, and all its keys

```
Key = level1_key.level2_key.level3_key.status
Data = down
```

Because there are 5 elements in the dict (4 keys and 1 string) I would end up with 5 tuples of key paths and data.

The reason behind this is that each element represents configuration, if say the "status" needs changing to "down" what actually needs changing is: level1_key.level2_key.level3_key.status

A non-working example I wrote which gets all the strings, their keys, and partial root paths, but it doesn't quite get all the root keys

```
current_key = ""
key_list = []

def thing(data):
    global current_key
    global key_list
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            current_key = key
            key_list.append(key)
            thing(value)
    elif isinstance(data, str):

        print(f"Key: {current_key}")
        print(f"Key List: {key_list}")
        print(f"Data: {data}")
        print("##########")
        key_list = []
```

```
Data is:
{
  "100": {
    "status": "down"
  },
  "200": {
    "status1": "up",
    "status2": "down",
    "status3": {
      "nested": "more_data"
    }
  }
}
Key: status
Key List: [100, 'status']
Data: down
##########
Key: status1
Key List: [200, 'status1']
Data: up
##########
Key: status2
Key List: ['status2']
Data: down
##########
Key: nested
Key List: ['status3', 'nested']
Data: more_data
##########
```

The last bit "more_data" is missing a root key of 200 for example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tom Dalton Added one of many attempts I've written.